# How does the howl of a hyena sound like?

Tags: animal-identification, africa

I once heard an animal howl at night while camping in Damaraland, Namibia. I never saw the animal. However, I much later stumbled on a webcam footage where some animal (off-camera) sounded exactly the same, cf. see this YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6ZisvkI2XU&t=219s) at about minute 3:38. The author of the video claims that it is a spotted hyena (*Crocuta crocuta*), however, after scouring the web for vocalizations of the spotted hyena, I haven't managed to find that exact same howl. (They typically pitch their "howl" up or down at the end, whereas what I heard had a more or less steady frequency as you can hear from the video.)

Comment: Try this: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=hyena+laugh

Comment: @DJClayworth I checked that already, but none of those laughs sound like in that video I linked to. Besides, it wasn't a laugh, but more of a howl. Actually it sounded almost like the wind blowing through the crack of a window/door.

Comment: Then I suspect that's your answer.

Comment: Was it also a cracked door in that video I linked to?

Comment: Wolves and dogs are more likely to howl.

Comment: @Yogesch I know, but that wasn't a dog you heard in the video, was it? As for wolves, there are none in that part of the world.

Comment: Yeah I heard it closely now. It is not an actual howl sound. And recorded hyena sounds are mostly much higher in pitch. So when I first commented, I said dog, BUT - recorded **wild** dog sounds are also much higher pitch (almost chirpy like a bird). So it is not a (wild) dog. The YouTube comments say it is the hyena calling, and I am inclined to agree mainly because there are no other animals in sight and it seems reasonable for the hyena in that location to be calling out to its pack mates.

Comment: @Yogesch The problem is that I couldn't find a *single* video recording of hyenas sounding like that. If one looks up hyena vocalizations on YouTube, they sound distinctly different from this one.

Comment: @Tfovid Thanks to your persistence, I found some very good information on the topic. Apparently hyenas have 14 different sounds. Check out the links in the answer.

Comment: @Tfovid if you feel the question is answered by the submitted answer, feel fee to accept it, or perhaps add a bounty to encourage someone else to write a better answer

Comment: @Yogesch You're answer is very good. Unless anyone comes up with something better in the next few days, I'll go ahead an accept it. (I'm afraid I can't afford a bounty at this point.) The one thing I was hoping for is an actual recording of the hyena vocalizing that way so as to remove that last inkling of doubt, but I'll do without it since your elaboration was convincing.

Comment: Check the YouTube video I linked to in the answer around 3:10 and 13:03 and also in the video on the Thomson Safari page around 0:12. While not an exact match, it seems to come pretty close..

Comment: I did... I was hoping for an exact match. But just give me a few another week or so :-)

Comment: Check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIQSVQL7VXg listen closely around 0:30 in the background. If you want to search further, you should be looking for "hyena whoop sounds"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyenas have a few different kinds of vocalizations. The most well known of these is the cackle/laugh of which there are many recordings and videos. Understandably, it is difficult for a human to get the opportunity to hear the different sounds wild animals make in different circumstances. It is even more difficult to have the opportunity and the gear to make an actual recording of it. So the recordings that are commonly found are the most frequent type of vocalization that the animals make.

I quote below from [this Quora answer](https://qr.ae/pGB1NH)

> Besides the cackle, hyenas make another type of sound A slow,
> plaintive, drawn out “WHOOooooooOOP”. It’s an essential part of the
> soundtrack of most African safaris, for it’s the sound you listen to
> as you lie in your camp at night. This is a bit like a wolf howl in
> that it lets other members of the group know where each individual is
> by their distinctive voice as they whoop.

According to other sources, Hyenas are reported to have upto 14 different types of calls from growls to shrieks. Check out [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBb7Rng8ir0) of a guy who got real up close with a bunch of hyenas.

I quote again, this time from [Thomson Safaris](https://thomsonsafaris.com/blog/hyena-calls-grunts-whoop/)

> But what’s that strange, whooping call, like an animal with a slide-whistle lodged in its throat? Or the eerie, low-pitched “oooh” that sounds something like a recording of a space alien being played back at 1/10th the speed? Or the rapid, high-pitched staccato screeching? Didn’t the guide say there were no chimpanzee near this campsite?

> Believe it or not, all those strange sounds come from hyena, too. From rumbling bass growls to strange, shrieking squeals, hyena use a wide range of vocalizations to communicate with one another and with other predators.

So, based on listening to the different kinds of vocalizations in the videos linked to here, I am almost certain that's the sound of a hyena. And the sound is not a howl but it is called *whoop*, in the recording it sounds like an extended whoop.